# QRegularExpression For Phone Number

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregularexpression

I am trying to use regular expressions to validate phone numbers but its just allowing all numbers to be accepted not just 10, my regular expression is ^[0-9]{10} which should just allow 10 numbers 0-9. my test strings were 1234567890 which passed and 703482062323 which also passed. What can i do to fix this issue?

The code im using to test the regular expression is

```
QRegularExpression Phone_Num("^[0-9]{10}"); // 10 numbers in a phone number
QRegularExpressionMatch match = Phone_Num.match("12345612312312312121237890");
qDebug() << match.hasMatch();
```

Comment: Try removing the `^`

Comment: its still accepting more than 10 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you really want **exactly** 10:

^[0-9]{10}$

match end-of-line so that it doesn't match a subset of a line with more than 10.

```
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QDebug>

int main() {
    QRegularExpression re("^[0-9]{10}$");
    qDebug() << re.match("12345678901123").hasMatch();
    qDebug() << re.match("1234567890").hasMatch();
    qDebug() << re.match("12345678").hasMatch();
    qDebug() << re.match("123123123a").hasMatch();
}
```

output:

```
false
true
false
false
```

Comment: you don't need to use capturing groups just `^[0-9]{10}$` would be enough.

Comment: correct. edited. dunno why i put them there, probably just reflex. @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/sS0nS2/1), please. Your regex is OK as every string *containing* at least 10 digits will pass. You can use grouping like that: `([0-9]{10})` and then extract the group somehow (see [this](https://regex101.com/r/sS0nS2/2)).